# Android Service Work Flow

Tags: android, service

I am trying to create a simple REST client in android, i have created the client that makes the connections and the service intent. I can call it from the main activity but i have a problem getting the result from the service intent to the activity. How can i achive this? I am kind of confused on how to handle this...

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_AUTH.equals(action)) {
            final String username = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM_USERNAME);
            final String password = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PARAM_PASSWORD);
            boolean authenticated = handleActionAuth(username, password);
            Log.d(TAG, "Result: "+authenticated);
            /*** What can i call here to notify the activity??? ***/
        } else if (ACTION_BAZ.equals(action)) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: read about "bound services"

Comment: @pskink that was my first aproach, i failed to send a message back to the activity... Do you maybe have an example?

Comment: Call the rest service from an asynctask within the activity. You don't need a service for that!

Comment: where did you fail? when calling service just pass a reference to some interface your Activity implements and your service will be able to call your interface method